# Adding HTML URL to Wordpress functions.php crashes site

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Using the **functions.php** in my Wordpress-installation lets me edit the footer-portion of the theme. However, I'm trying to add a link in the text using the standard `<a href= ...` but this crashes the site.

This is what I'm working with right now:

```
function my_footer_info() {
  $my_footer_info = '<div class="copyright">'.__( "For programs and periodization, click here.</br> Copyright © ", 'spacious' ).' 2016  site.html'.'</div>';
    echo do_shortcode( $my_footer_info );
```

That works and the text is visible on the site without problem. However, adding this crashes the site:

```
<a href = "site.html" > click here < /a >
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this in functions.php

hook in your own function like:

```
add_action( 'REPLACE YOUR WEBSITE NAME HERE_footer, 'my_footer_content' );

function my_footer_content() 
{

echo '<div class="copyright">'.__( "For programs and periodization, 
click here.</br> Copyright © ", 'spacious' ).' 2016  site.html'.'</div>';
}
```